# Validate the email address in UITextField in iphone

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ensure User has entered email address string in correct format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094658/ensure-user-has-entered-email-address-string-in-correct-format)

I have `UITextField` in which I take the email address from user that they enter, and I want to validate that email address, such as I would it should check that it contains symbols like @ sign and other email characters.

If there is an error in the email address then it should show a `UIAlertView` that would say "enter a valid email address".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Objective C Style**

```
NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,10}";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];

if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:email.text] == NO) {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test!" message:@"Please Enter Valid Email Address." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

    return;
}
```

**Swift Style**

```
class func isValidEmail(emailString:String) -> Bool {

    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,10}"
    var emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)

    let result = emailTest?.evaluateWithObject(emailString)
    return result!
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using NSPredicate

```
//suppose emailID is your entered email address NSString
NSString *emailFormat1 = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";     


NSPredicate *emailTest1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailFormat1]; 


if ([emailTest1 evaluateWithObject:emailID]||[emailTest2 evaluateWithObject:emailID]) {
   //yes it is valid
}
else
    //no it is invalid
```

Answer (score 1):

Add [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/) to the project and find the solutions below.

1. [Best practices for validating email address in Objective-C on iOS 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800123/best-practices-for-validating-email-address-in-objective-c-on-ios-2-0)
2. [How to validate email field in uitextfield in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068859/how-to-validate-email-field-in-uitextfield-in-iphone)